# Tags for things that aren't on topic?

Tags: discussion

I asked this question - [How to get rid of tiny brown ants?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/278161/how-to-get-rid-of-tiny-brown-ants?noredirect=1#comment575763_278161)

Simple question, chose ants and pest-control as tags.

Then was told that question is off-topic?   What?    How can a question be off-topic if the exact tags of what the question is, are in the system.

Is the question off-topic, if so then why aren't the tags being deleted.   Are there questions like... what kind of ants do you use to frame a house or what kind of pest-control services also doing electrical wiring?

Comment: In before someone tells me discussion questions are off-topic.

Comment: LOL. I think that meta may have died. I posted a question a week ago and hasn't had a single response.

Comment: @FreeMan - I am fine with site being less maintenance.   I don't understand topics that were good for almost 10 years with their own tags being off topic... It seems a minority has decided to work this.   Maybe they just don't understand.   DIY has always been about the complete building and maintenance of a house.

Comment: @FreeMan - SE is hard to swallow.   I had a couple questions on meta that were handled very poorly.   Couple that with the fact that you are allowed to denounce many cultures but certain ones are very off limits is disturbing.    I try to ignore that stuff but I actually cancelled SE at my work (~1m a year) because of this.    The SE mods - that work for SE - are like a bunch of attacking teenagers.    And this is my observation...   The PC issue is a systemic issue.   Couple that with AI spitting out our answers and we don't get paid... ouch.

Comment: Fortunately, I see very little of that here at DIY, and that's why it's the only site I regularly visit any more.

Comment: @FreeMan - so true, this is one of the sites that has maintained the attitude of just trying to help others out.    Not even sure I add anything anywhere else now.